# Avoiding type conflicts with dplyr::case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am trying to use `dplyr::case_when` within `dplyr::mutate` to create a new variable where I set some values to missing and recode other values simultaneously.

However, if I try to set values to `NA`, I get an error saying that we cannot create the variable `new` because `NA`s are logical:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>     Evaluation error: must be type double, not logical.

Is there a way to set values to `NA` in a non-logical vector in a data frame using this?

```
library(dplyr)    

# Create data
df <- data.frame(old = 1:3)

# Create new variable
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(new = dplyr::case_when(old == 1 ~ 5,
                                                  old == 2 ~ NA,
                                                  TRUE ~ old))

# Desired output
c(5, NA, 3)
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As said in `?case_when`:

> All RHSs must evaluate to the same type of vector.

You actually have two possibilities:

**1) Create `new` as a numeric vector**

```
df <- df %>% mutate(new = case_when(old == 1 ~ 5,
                                    old == 2 ~ NA_real_,
                                    TRUE ~ as.numeric(old)))
```

Note that `NA_real_` is the numeric version of `NA`, and that you must convert `old` to numeric because you created it as an integer in your original dataframe.

You get:

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ old: int  1 2 3
# $ new: num  5 NA 3
```

**2) Create `new` as an integer vector**

```
df <- df %>% mutate(new = case_when(old == 1 ~ 5L,
                                    old == 2 ~ NA_integer_,
                                    TRUE ~ old))
```

Here, `5L` forces 5 into the integer type, and `NA_integer_` is the integer version of `NA`.

So this time `new` is integer:

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ old: int  1 2 3
# $ new: int  5 NA 3
```

Comment: You can also do `as.numeric(NA)` or `as.integer(NA)` for the `NA` cases, as `NA_real_` and `NA_integer_` are a bit annoying to remember and rarely used outside of things like this.

Comment: Nice. Also, to show: identical(NA_real_,as.numeric(NA)) produces TRUE.

Comment: @hadley This answer is now clear to me, but it took me awhile to figure out.  It would be very helpful to have an example of this in the tidyverse `case_when` documentation. In my case when missing all values for grouped data, mean(x[1:2], na.rm=T) were generating an NaN result. recoding those cases to NA_real_ fixed it.

Comment: @MattL. Hadley won't be pinged, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more details on how notifications work. However the documentation was clarified last week by this PR: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/3247

Comment: When inserting `NA` placeholders into a column of class `Date`, use `as.Date(NA)` to produce the `NA`

Comment: @Marius's solution also works with as.character. Simple and versatile

Answer (score 5):

Try this ?

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(new = dplyr::case_when(.$old == 1 ~ 5,
                                                  .$old == 2 ~ NA_real_,
                                                  TRUE~.$old))

> df
  old new
1   1   5
2   2  NA
3   3   3
```

Comment: does `.$old` make a difference? Doesn't this return the same as `old`, as we're dealing with the full dataframe?