# How to recode only some values in R to NA using dplyr::if_else?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling, recode

I want to recode values below 0 to NA with dpylr::if_else, leaving all other values unchanged. I know there are other ways to do this, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work:
`data %>% mutate(x = if_else(x < 0, NA, x))`
R returns this:

> "`false` must be a logical vector, not a double vector."

I wish for `false` to remain the original values.

Comment: `data %>% mutate(x = if_else(x < 0, NA_real_, x))`. NA_real_ is the equivalent for numeric NA. `dplyr::if_else` is specifically written to force you to have the same type in your `true` and `false` arguments.

Comment: Note that this same issue will also happen if you use vectorized versions of `dplyr::if_else()` such as `dplyr::case_when()` which lets you do multiple `if_else()` statements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893933/avoiding-type-conflicts-with-dplyrcase-when

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `NA` is not the same type as the `x` in the `FALSE` condition. You can fix this by using `NA_real_` instead.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(-1,0,1))

# Use NA_real_
dat %>% mutate(z = if_else(x < 0, NA_real_, x))
#>    x  z
#> 1 -1 NA
#> 2  0  0
#> 3  1  1
```